# Efficient algorithm to extract a subgraph within a maximum distance from multiple vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have an algorithmic problem where there's a straightforward solution, but it seems wasteful. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do the same thing.

Here's the problem:

- Input: A large graph `G` with non-negative edge weights (interpreted as lengths), a list of vertices `v`, and a list of distances `d` the same length as `v`.
- Output: The subgraph `S` of `G` consisting of all of the vertices that are at a distance of at most `d[i]` from `v[i]` for some `i`.

The obvious solution is to use Dijkstra's algorithm starting from each `v[i]`, modified so that it bails out after hitting a distance of `d[i]`, and then taking the union of the subgraphs that each search traverses. However, in my use case it's frequently going to be the case that the search trees from the `v[i]`s overlap substantially. That means the Dijkstra approach will wastefully traverse the vertices in the overlap multiple times before I take the union.

In the case that there is only one vertex in `v`, the Dijkstra approach runs in `O(|S|log|S|)`, taking `|S|` to be the number of vertices (my graph is sparse, so I ignore the edges term). Is it possible to achieve the same asymptotic run time when `v` has more than one vertex?

My first idea was to combine the searches out of each `v[i]` into the same priority queue, but the "bail out" condition mentioned above complicates this approach. Sometimes a vertex will be reached in a shorter distance from one `v[i]`, but you would still want to search through it from another `v[j]` if the second vertex has a larger `d[j]` allotted to it.

Thanks!

Comment: If d contains infinities and v contains every vertex in G, total output will be O(|S|*|S|). You can't expect algorithm to work less than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with the complexity of a single Dijkstra run.

Let D be the maximum of the distances in d.

Define a new start vertex, and give it edges to each of the vertices in v.

The length of the edge between start and v[i] should be set to D-d[i].

Then in this new graph, S is given by all vertices within a length D of the start vertex, so apply Dijkstra to the start vertex.